# Bufferoverflow stack canary location

Tags: gdb, buffer-overflow, stack-smash

I have i binary that can be exploited with a buffer overflow, but it has a stack canary

I can get many addresses and values through a `gets()` call, but i cant locate the stack canary in `pwndbg`( version of `gdb`) so i can find out what of the values i get is the stack canary

I tried looking on the stack but cant find it and looked at a script that can already exploit it and it uses a canary value (by this i mean index of the leaked addresses from the `gets()` ) that i cant even find in the disassembler

Answer (score 2):

I am missing some key details here, but I'll try to give this a go.

Firstly, the canary is not going to be on the stack, but between stack frames:
https://manybutfinite.com/img/stack/bufferCanary.png

Googling "stack canary location gcc" yields a couple images to help you understand this mechanism more easily.

Secondly, I am not quite sure what do you mean by using gets() to read. gets() reads the stdin and puts it into a buffer. You will not be able to use it to read program memory.

Regarding the script that is already working: I am skeptical.

From the gcc docs (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html):

> The guards are initialized when a function is entered and then checked when the function exits.

It might be possible that the code that manages to exploit it either has stack protector turned off in the binary, or it finds another way to bypass this protection by some other means. You can, for example overflow a local function pointer and not trigger the stack protector at all. The stack protector only protects against overflowing into the stored RBP and RIP (32bit: EBP and EIP), not against overflowing into local variables.